# Cucumber Report giving empty response

Tags: spring-boot, cucumber, bdd

I am trying to generate cucumber report using SpringBoot application in BDD
I am using 1.2.6 version of info.cukes in my pom.xml and have included cucumber-junit,cucumber-java,cucumber-spring dependencies
Below is the Test Configuration for cucumber

```
@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(features = "classpath:src/test/resources/features",plugin = {"pretty","json:target/cucumber.json"},glue = "classpath:src/test/java/com")
public class ApplicationTests {
}
```

When I run my feature file, bdd runs perfectly fine and all the test are passed but when I see cucumber json file which is generated in target folder it is empty

Comment: tried with io.cucumber version 6.2.2 as well but still cucmber.json file is empty though all test scenario are passed

Answer (score 0):

You are using quite old version of Cucumber. My suggestion is to use version 6.7.0 and above. It has Cucumber Reports Service. It generates a very good report and is quite simple to generate.

1. Add Cucumber-jvm of version 6.7.0 and above in pom.xml.
2. Create Cucumber.properties file in src/test/resources and mention instruction in the file -

cucumber.publish.enabled=true

You are all set. Try to run the tests from command line using mvn test.